# Обработка строк в c#

Tags: c#

Есть строка и экземпляр строки, нужно их сравнить. Экземпляр типа "($, $, $)" $ - любой символ, строка например "(56.3, 34.0, 23.2)". Можно ли сделать это, без десятков проверок, а если возможно то как?

Comment: регулярные выражения?

Comment: Сравнить посимвольно?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, речь идет вот о чем: есть строка примерно такого формата

```
    "(56.3, 34.0, 23.2)"
```

Нужно написать метод, который скажет, входит ли выражение 23.2 в эту строку. При этом надо, чтобы мы не перепутали 23.2 с 123.2 или 23.28

Сделать это можно так:

1. выкидываем скорбки, заменяем их на пробел
2. запятые тоже  заменяем на пробелы
3. теперь у нас в строке все искомые выражения разделены (и окружены) пробелами: `56.3  34.0  23.2` Поставим по одному пробелу с каждой стороны строки, котрую ищем: `23.2`.

Теперь ответ на вопрос даст простой запрос

```
    " 56.3  34.0  23.2 ".IndexOf(" 23.2 ");
```